# What am I doing wrong in this exercise to remove vowels from a string?

Tags: python

The exercise it to return a given string without any of the vowels e.g.
"car" would return "cr".

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    #returns text without vowels
    answer = ""
    i = 0
    while i <= len(text) -1:
        for text[i] in "aeiouAEIOU" = False:
            answer += text[i]
            i += 1   
    answer = answer.join(text)

    return answer
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in this line:

```
for text[i] in "aeiouAEIOU" = False:
```

The `=` is for assignment, replace the whole line with the following:

```
for text[i] not in "aeiouAEIOU":
```

You also have a problem with indentation, your whole function should look like this:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    #returns text without vowels
    answer = ""
    i = 0
    while i <= len(text) -1:
        for text[i] not in "aeiouAEIOU":
            answer += text[i]
        i += 1   
    answer = answer.join(text)

    return answer
```

And this would be the Pythonic version:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    return ''.join(c for c in text if c.lower() not in "aeiou")
```